# While loop not working with a database

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop

Can somebody help me with a while loop? Because it's not working

Here is my code:

```
$signup = "SELECT * FROM ISPD_signup WHERE ID_user = " .$id;
```

And here is my table:

If I remove the while out of the `mysqli_fetch_array($alleleden)` it will only read out one member that registered and if I leave the while it won't read out anything.

```
$alleleden = mysqli_query($mysqli, $signup); 

if (mysqli_num_rows ($alleleden) == 0)
{
    echo "<p>Er zijn geen inschrijvingen gevonden! </p>";
}
else 
{ 
    echo "<h4>Inschrijvingen: </h4>"; 
    echo "<table>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<th class='hide'>ID </th>";
    echo "<th>Naam </th>";
    echo "<th>Beslissing </th>";
    echo "</tr>"; 

    while ($lid = mysqli_fetch_array($alleleden));
    {
        echo "<tr>"; 
        echo "<td class='hide'>" . $lid['ID'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $lid['Naam'] . "</td>";   
        echo "<td>" . $lid['Beslissing'] . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>"; 

    }
    echo "</table>";
}
```

Comment: Debug time.. var_dump($alleleden); should be a mysql result resource.. if it's false your query is incorrect or your to using the right database.

Comment: Side note SQL injection looks like is possible  in your php code... you should use the function prepare or use cast like this.`$signup = "SELECT * FROM ISPD_signup WHERE ID_user = " .(int)$id;`

Comment: @RaymondNijland I tend to agree with the possible injection, however we don't know if the OP already assigned it as `$id = (int)$_GET['id'];` before that. If that is the case, then it's not open to an sql injection; fair point though ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- change mine comment that it looks like SQL injection is possible

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You place a extra semicolon in while loop

```
$alleleden = mysqli_query($mysqli, $signup); 

if (mysqli_num_rows ($alleleden) == 0)
{
    echo "<p>Er zijn geen inschrijvingen gevonden! </p>";
}
else 
{
echo "<h4>Inschrijvingen: </h4>";     
echo "<table>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<th class='hide'>ID </th>";
echo "<th>Naam </th>";
echo "<th>Beslissing </th>";
echo "</tr>"; 


while ($lid = mysqli_fetch_array($alleleden))
{
        echo "<tr>"; 
        echo "<td class='hide'>" . $lid['ID'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $lid['Naam'] . "</td>";   
        echo "<td>" . $lid['Beslissing'] . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>"; 
}
echo "</table>";
}
```

Try this code its works.

Comment: believe it or not but ; after the while still executes the while loop and isn't likly to be the problem in this code http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/071d9c016fdb74d014846249c2addfdbd7703abc

Comment: Lol....!
but not in the syntax of while while().
its in while(){**here**}.

Answer (score 4):

The problem here is the semi-colon at the end of this loop

```
while ($lid = mysqli_fetch_array($alleleden)); // <<< there
```

you need to remove it

```
while ($lid = mysqli_fetch_array($alleleden))
```

and since it's a valid (end of) statement character in php, it won't throw an error for it.

- http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.instruction-separation.php

> As in C or Perl, PHP requires instructions to be terminated with a semicolon at the end of each statement. The closing tag of a block of PHP code automatically implies a semicolon; you do not need to have a semicolon terminating the last line of a PHP block. The closing tag for the block will include the immediately trailing newline if one is present.

Plus, you might want to use `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` instead of `mysqli_fetch_array()`.

Side note: You may be open to an sql injection here so either use a prepared statement or use:

```
$id = (int)$_GET['id'];
```

That will also prevent an injection by assigning it as an integer right away.

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement
- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

Comment: believe it or not but ; after the while still executes the while loop and isn't likly to be the problem in this code http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/071d9c016fdb74d014846249c2addfdbd7703abc

Comment: @RaymondNijland Yes I know, and I've seen that before. But this is mysql going over records in a database; it's a different animal ;-) it *is* the problem here.

Comment: added a upvote because the topicstarter commented the semi-colon was the problem.. and i had proven the semi-colon was not likly the problem..PHP sometimes has wierd random features.. normally you indeed shouldn't write a semi-colon after the while loop

Comment: @RaymondNijland Thanks Raymond. Yeah... the loop setup in the way you had the demo is indeed something that is quirky compared to going over database records in mysql; quite and odd behaviour I might say :-))